# Search input with multiple columns just in 1 input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

well i have a search input on my website ( cars website ) and im using that search input to search only the cars by their brand... lets say Audi, BMW, etc... im wondering if there's a way i can type like:

Audi R8 and instead of showing nothing, it will show that car, like
SELECT brand, model FROM cars WHERE brand = firstspace, model=secondspace...

Something like that instead of creating two inputs... so i can only type inside that input the full name Audi R8 Spyder or just Audi R8 and it will show only the R8 models...

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, but  im currently using this: "SELECT * FROM automoviles WHERE marca like '$marca' or modelo like '$marca' or version like '$marca' LIMIT $offset, $limit"; BUT if i type Audi R8 ( it will return nothing ), not even Audi R8 model :p BUT if i type only audi it will return the car...

Comment: Add % before and after your variable. "SELECT * FROM automoviles WHERE marca like '%$marca%' or modelo like '%$marca%' or version like '%$marca%' LIMIT $offset, $limit";

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply i tried that code, i did the first search with Audi word only, got this: https://i.gyazo.com/d27b29d160188f1e97cbf9529358cd61.png but with Audi R8 got nothing again :( https://i.gyazo.com/4e27b1e5d1b84256b28e0e7a81929182.png

Comment: It will not show because marca and modelo are different columns. You can use php explode() to separate the string input and set it to different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 <?php        
       $input = 'Audi R8';
       $arr = explode(' ', $input); //to separate the input
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM automoviles WHERE marca like '%$arr[0]%' or modelo like '%$arr[1]%'";        
 ?>
```

**Edit 1** with escaping

```
<?php 
        $input = 'Audi R8';
        $arr = explode(' ', $input);
        $input1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $arr[0]);
        $input2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $arr[1]);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM automoviles WHERE marca like '%$input1%' or modelo like '%$input2%'";  
?>
```

Comment: Also data needs escaping before being sent to db, in order to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: Sometimes user may enter `R8 Audi` instead of `Audi R8`, or may enter more than 2 words, for example `red Audi R8`. Actually they usually do that. So this algorithm needs another improvement. :) For example search each word in each field...

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use explode function of php so that you will get two variables.

```
<?php
$dcs_str = "audi m8";
$dcs_arr = explode(" ",$dcs_str); ?>
```

Comment: After i get those 2 variables, how i can use them separately?  like marca = variable1 or model=variable2 ?

Comment: Use the foreach loop to use these variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate that input into two. For example like this :

```
var input = "Audi R8";
var space = input.indexOf(" ");
var firstspace = input.substring(0, space); // Audi
var secondspace = input.substring(space); // R8
```

So your sql would be like this :

```
SELECT brand, model FROM cars WHERE brand = firstspace, model=secondspace
```